# Detect if Webview scroll reach the end

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview

am trying to figure out the **max scroll** position that the `WebView` can reach, i've tried the `webView.pageDown(true)` but the result is delayed ( i cant scroll it down, then up infront of the user, and this method doesn't work every time), i've tried also `webView.getContentHeight()` and the height isn't correct for **Arabic** content.

Please Advice

Comment: Why do you want to know the max scroll position?

Comment: am trying to make pages from `WebView` content, the user must not scroll through the content, we must make it pages, so when i scroll down using `scrollTo` i cant figure if i reached the end or not, this is the requirement

Answer (score 16, accepted):

ok, i figured out the answer

you can get the real content height using

> (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * webView.getScale());

when you get the real height, then just override the scroll method in webview to listen to scroll event, if the scroll reach the real height, your webview is in the bottom of the scroll.

Comment: @Override
 public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
  int lenght =(int) Math.floor(WebView1.getContentHeight() * WebView1.getScale());
  
  return false;
 }                                                          How do you come to know by this the page has reached to end.......

Comment: @VipinSahu See my answer to

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10956443/android-making-a-button-visible-once-webview-is-done-scrolling

for a comprehensive solution.

Comment: WebView.getScale is deprecated, we should use getScaleY and getScaleX instead.

Answer (score 8):

```
@Override
public void onScroll(int l, int t) {
    int height = (int) Math.floor(webView.getContentHeight() * webView.getScale());
    int webViewHeight = webView.getHeight();
    int cutoff = height - webViewHeight - 10; // Don't be too strict on the cutoff point
    if (t >= cutoff) {
        setDisclaimerButtonEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The non-strictness is required, is because I found on the Samsung S5 the bottom most scroll value was only 1 pixel value away from the bottom most value!

Comment: this is due to Math.floor(). try Math.round()

Comment: how to i override the `onScroll(int l, int t)` method?

Comment: What is does the int t represent?

Answer (score -1):

Loading / Visible button only when webview reached / scrolled to bottom.

Create JavaScript class :

```
public class JavaScriptInterface {

  @android.webkit.JavascriptInterface
  public void didScrollToBottom() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Scroll to Bottom");
    myHandler.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         btnAccept.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

          }
       });
      }
    }
```

In onCreate() :

```
final JavaScriptInterface jsInterface = new JavaScriptInterface();
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "AndroidFunction");
```