# Getting WebView Content height once its loaded Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I'm trying to apply expand collapse feature on Webview Based on its Content height but i'm always getting wrong value 
Here is my code

```
public class MesuredHeightWebView extends WebView {
    public MesuredHeightWebView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MesuredHeightWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MesuredHeightWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }



    @Override
    public void invalidate() {
        super.invalidate();

        if (getContentHeight() > 0) {
            // WebView has displayed some content and is scrollable.
            if(listener!=null)
                listener.updateContentHeight(getContentHeight());
        }
    }



    WebViewContentHeight listener;

    public void setChangeContentListener(WebViewContentHeight listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }
}
```

and then in the fragment i tried to get the content height

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient(){
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

            super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
            if(newProgress==100)
            {
                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        webView.setChangeContentListener(new WebViewContentHeight() {
                            @Override
                            public void updateContentHeight(int height) {

                                if(height>0 && getActivity()!=null) {

                                    System.out.println("the height2 is" + height + " " + Utils.convertPixelsToDp(height, getActivity()));
                                    final int text_height = height;
```

but my problem is that i'm always getting wrong result 
Thanks

Comment: Can you explain why ContentListener must be within a runnable? Can't we get an accurate value if we simply set the listener without it?

Answer (score 18):

Use the following methods instead of `getContentHeight()` method:

```
computeHorizontalScrollRange(); -> for width 
computeVerticalScrollRange(); -> for height
```

these two methods will return the entire scrollable width/height rather than the actual widht/height of the webview on screen

Comment: Thanks Man, It Works like a Charm

Comment: Thanks a lot, great answer!

Comment: Using it with combination of onScrolledSchanged() gives you more efficient way to handle top, bottom.

Comment: these methods are for scrollview, the question is posed for webview. I'm in a situation where I need just the webview height, not the whole scroll view

Comment: @Siavash the vertical scrollrange is actually the height of the webview

Comment: can't find these methods? Howto use them ? no such methods for webview.