# Making ViewPager + WebView swipe vertical in continuous way

Tags: android, html, webview, android-viewpager

I'm writing a html page reader, cant load all .html because its huge and performance is bad, so I decided to split it into 3(or more) html and load that inside Web View nested with View Pager (swipe vertically)

My problem is that I should swipe slowly to scroll the web view and swipe fast to change view pager

Slow swiping

[image]

fast swipe change the Page on ViewPager

[image]

1) Can i expand webview to all its content heigh inside viewpager ?
2) Can change viewpager item only when topScroll or endScroll?

what i've tried so far:

CustomWebView

```
 @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
```

worked but was unable to change viewpager item

so i though about enable/disable it when i get to the top or to the end

removed webview onTouchEvent and added:

```
   @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(final int l, final int t, final int oldl, final int oldt) {
        requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);



        int height = (int) Math.floor(this.getContentHeight() * this.getScale());
        int webViewHeight = this.getMeasuredHeight();

        boolean scrollTop = this.getTop() == t;
        boolean scrollEnd = this.getScrollY() + webViewHeight >= height;

        if(scrollTop || scrollEnd) {
            requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
        }
```

worked randomly, the most common thing is that when i change page, i must scroll down and scroll up to trigger the requestDisallow to false so i can change page =[

Vertical CustomViewPage is this one ->

```
public class VerticalViewPager extends ViewPager {

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public VerticalViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        // The majority of the magic happens here
        setPageTransformer(true, new VerticalPageTransformer());
        // The easiest way to get rid of the overscroll drawing that happens on the left and right
        setOverScrollMode(OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
    }

    private class VerticalPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        @Override
        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                view.setAlpha(0);

            } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]
                view.setAlpha(1);

                // Counteract the default slide transition
                view.setTranslationX(view.getWidth() * -position);

                //set Y position to swipe in from top
                float yPosition = position * view.getHeight();
                view.setTranslationY(yPosition);

            } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                view.setAlpha(0);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Swaps the X and Y coordinates of your touch event.
     */
    private MotionEvent swapXY(MotionEvent ev) {
        float width = getWidth();
        float height = getHeight();

        float newX = (ev.getY() / height) * width;
        float newY = (ev.getX() / width) * height;

        ev.setLocation(newX, newY);

        return ev;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev){
        boolean intercepted = super.onInterceptTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
        swapXY(ev); // return touch coordinates to original reference frame for any child views
        return intercepted;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return super.onTouchEvent(swapXY(ev));
    }

}
```

Comment: have you tried to add it in scroll view ?

Comment: @g33k yep, nothing changed, when i scroll fast, the viewpager change the page (and using RequestDisallowIntercept, disable viewpager)

Comment: have you done this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- 1st i think it's a bad idea to split your content into 3 different HTML files and putting them on 3 different WebViews.
- 3 fils can be a good idea but 3 WebView in 3 Views of ViewPager is a bad idea.
- Instead, you should detect top and bottom of the webpage using "**.js**" / "**jQuery**" and route page/HTML within same WebView.

  window.onscroll = function(ev) {
      if ((window.innerHeight + window.scrollY) >= document.body.offsetHeight) {
          // you're at the bottom of the page
      }};

There are many ways to detect TOP and BOTTOM of your HTML content.

Still, if you want to increase the height of your review to content height use 
[Getting WebView Content height once its loaded Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36281875/getting-webview-content-height-once-its-loaded-android) it worked for me.

Comment: huuumm, i understand, can be a good idea, will study and check if could be a good choice and return here

Comment: do you have some apps in mind that do this? Can you download readEra and open a ebook, u will see the request things, i tried to find some source about, but no success